# Reading someone else's Gmail inbox if you have their session URL

Tags: gmail, security

Is it possible for someone to gain access to my Gmail inbox if they use a link from when I was logged in?

I was trying to copy a link from an email in Gmail and accidentally copied the URL in the address bar. It looked similar to this bogus link:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/v/5/?emai=9#inbox/2547h5w9hdkrslb27
```

Then I posted that link on Facebook. I was able to remove the link but I am concerned that the link gives hackers an easier way to hack into my Gmail.

Are my fears real or unfounded?

This is probably more paranoia than anything but I would rather be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfounded.

You need to be authenticated to actually view any emails.

Just to show you how sure I am, [here is a link to one of my emails](https://mail.google.com/mail/#inbox/132281dc96490751).

Unless you are authenticated as the user who "owns" that email, it will just redirect you to the inbox (tested with another account).

Comment: Thanks, BTW your mom left you an email, no emergency. =>

Comment: @Lynda - She doesn't know that address! :P

Comment: I promise I won't tell.